# How can I get the current templating on Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to get the current html page as a string (for example) after Angularjs proceeded to rendering template.

The aim is to send this content to my server.

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ( $scope, $location) {

 // 1- get the current html content of my web page

// 2- send it to my server 

}])
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Or may be an advise ? I would like send the current html page to my server. As this page is already compiled, well formated (html+css) and already downloaded on user computer... I would like to send it to my server and I would like reuse it to send via an email to the customer. Voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the current content of the page using

```
angular.element('html').html()
```

Use the $http service to send data back to server after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a directive that runs your code in the link function. The link function is called after the template is built.

Directive:

```
test.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("variable", function (value) {
            var val = value || null;
            if (val) {
                element('html').html();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

In HTML

```
<body my-directive></body>
```